# Français d'Afrique

Tags: ressources, afrique

J'aimerais beaucoup lire un livre relativement général (pas forcément en français, d'ailleurs) sur le français d'Afrique. Je suis ouvert à des choses assez différentes (livre d'introduction générale, livre constitué de chapitres indépendants sur plusieurs aspects de la question ou plusieurs régions, livre plus théorique ou universitaire...) J'aimerais surtout éviter une liste fastidieuse d'africanismes ou une étude trop localisée géographiquement.

Si en plus le livre contient des informations (voire est centré) sur la façon dont les langues locales influencent le français, tant du point de vue lexicographique que grammatical, c'est encore mieux !

Avez-vous des références à me conseiller ?

---

I'd love to read a relatively general book about African French. It can be in any reasonable language, targetted to a general audience or to linguists, I'm not picky. The only things I'd like to avoid are a mere list of Africanisms or a study whose (geographical) scope is too narrow.

I'm particularly interested in how the local substrate influences African French vocabulary and grammar, so the more the book deals with that, the merrier I will be...

Do you have references to recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voici quelques références, dont la première semble correspondre précisément à tes critères de recherche:

- [La diversité du français et l’enseignement de la langue en Afrique](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2747564738), Paris : L’Harmattan, 2004, 180 p. de KWOFIE Emmanuel

  *Cet ouvrage présente des études sur le français en Francophonie, d’une part les rapports entre le français d’Afrique et la langue française en général, d’autre part la notion même de français d’Afrique.*
- [La Francophonie autrement : héritage senghorien](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2296052304), Paris : L’Harmattan, 2008, 245 p. de DUMONT Pierre

  *L’auteur, impliqué dans la rénovation des systèmes éducatifs au sein de l’espace francophone et plus particulièrement en Afrique, livre ses réflexions sur la francophonie. La prise en compte de la pluralité des situations qui constituent l’espace francophone est essentielle et doit permettre un enseignement de la langue française différent. A ce titre la convergence didactique du français et des langues partenaires, un des sujets du congrès mondial de la Fédération internationale des Professeurs de Français (FIPF) de juillet 2008, doit être l’objet d’une évaluation. (Résumé de l’éditeur)*
- Le français langue seconde et sa fonction d’enseignement en Afrique francophone : problèmes et perspectives, Paris : PUF, 2005, p.183-205 de SPAETH Valérie

  *Dans ce chapitre, l’auteur rappelle la complexité de la situation sociolinguistique en Afrique et propose une réflexion sur la notion de français langue seconde pour entrer plus précisément dans la problématique de langue d’enseignement : quelle didactique pour les contextes plurilingues africains.*

Source: [La langue française dans l’espace francophone : promotion et diffusion](http://www.ciep.fr/bibliographie/bibliographie-francophonie.pdf)

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ta réponse (je suis impardonnable : rechercher « français, Afrique » dans le catalogue de l'Harmattan aurait dû être mon premier réflexe...) Mais ta réponse va bien au-delà, donc mon idiotie se trouve récompensée :-)